# Encode OpenGL rendered video without leaving the GPU memory

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, cuvid

I am doing some preliminary work to make a rendering pipeline and I am investigating whether OpenGL is a good option for my use case: from a markup language I need to generate a video, ideally using opengl which already implements most of the primitives I need.

Is there a way to, instead of (or additionally to) updating a framebuffer, to make an mp4 video file using nvenc, without copying data back and forth between the GPU's and main memory?

Answer (score 0):

The nvenc SDK page[1] on the NVidia website suggests that it can, as the current header graphic is of a game being streamed. (Even if it's a Direct3D game, same chip underneath.) A quick search for "nvenc share buffer with OpenGL" turned up a number of people apparently combining the two.

Runs on Linux and MS Windows only, so no joy if you have a Mac.

Hope this helps.